# Should type checking to be included when developing a Node.js library?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, typechecking

I'm currently developing a Node.js library that will be published to npm publicly. I'm not sure whether I should include type-checking code in the exported functions. Is there any best practice about this? I have a few ideas but I don't know which one is the best.

1. Include the type-checking code all time:

   ```js
   export function exportedFunction(callback)
   {
       if (typeof callback !== "function")
       {
           throw new TypeError("`callback` is not a function.");
       }

       ...
   }
   ```
2. Warp the type-checking code in a `if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production")` block:

   ```js
   export function exportedFunction(callback)
   {
       if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production")
       {
           if (typeof callback !== "function")
           {
               throw new TypeError("`callback` is not a function.");
           }
       }

       ...
   }
   ```
3. Not include the type-checking code at all:

   ```js
   export function exportedFunction(callback)
   {
       ...
   }
   ```

The first one can ensure the arguments provided by the caller is correct at all time. But the second one could avoid the type-checking code affecting the execution time when used in production. And the third one is...okay, it is bad.

Comment: having tests for a public facing library is a must - include type checking if you think that'll yield more benefit (for community development) - raising Errors is useful to denote runtime errors (and interfaces for your library) - tho its all dependant on the situation

Comment: It is not common (unless very special cases), you cannot do it properly most of the times and it would kill performance to check types dynamically. It is the way language is designed. You will get used to it.